# How to handle OptimisticLockException in JPA/hibernate in jboss?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x

I am using JPA to handle entities in JBOSS.One Entity will be updated by several threads in various transactions.I have @Version attribute added in my entity and also before updating entity i am obtaining OptimisticLock.I cant handle the exceptions and retry if transaction fails.

**The Entity is**

```
@Entity  
public class DataEntity   
{  
    @Id  
    int id;  
    long count;  
    @Version  
    int versionAttribute;  
     ....  
     ....
```

**The Code which updates the entities is**

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateEntity()  
{  
     DataEntity d=entityManager.find(DataEntity.class,0,LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
     d.setCount(d.getCount()+1);  
}
```

As you  can see the method updateEntity() uses TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW to have a new transaction.  Here transactions are container managed.So help me on doing a retry when an OptimisticLockingException is Thrown.

Where to handle exception? /Where to write the retry Logic?

Answer (score 1):

What about handling out of transaction boundary?

```
public class SafeHandleInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger();
private int maxRetryCount = 3;

public void setMaxRetryCount(int maxRetryCount) {
    this.maxRetryCount = maxRetryCount;
}

@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    int retryCount = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            ReflectiveMethodInvocation inv = (ReflectiveMethodInvocation) invocation;
            // clone before proceed, each inv could be proceed only once
            MethodInvocation anotherInvocation = inv.invocableClone();
            return anotherInvocation.proceed();
        } catch (OptimisticException e) {
            if (retryCount++ >= maxRetryCount) {
                throw e;
            } else {
                logger.info("retry for exception:" + e.getMessage(), e);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

weaving:

```
<bean id="your original transactional bean name" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="reference to your original transactional bean" />
    <property name="proxyInterfaces"
        value="your interface" />
    <property name="interceptorNames" value="safeHandleInterceptor" />
</bean>
```